# secure stripe payment integration in iOS app version<8

Tags: ios, ios7, stripe-payments

I just read about `stripe` payment integration in `iOS 8` for `Apple Pay`.

How can I use `stripe` for `iOS version less than 8`? I mean how secure is it?

`Stripe` just requires `CVV(that too optional)`, `Card Holder Name`, `Expiry date` and `Card Number` to initiate a payment. From these details, a `tokenID` is generated and the payment is done.

Now for instance my credit card goes into someone else's hand, all he needs is to enter my card details and make a payment. No password required and my money is gone.

Is there any step that I am missing(e.g. entering a password that only the card holder knows)?

Can I use `Stripe` for making secure payments with iOS version less than 8(i.e. versions without Apple pay)?

Comment: The CCV is required for card not present transactions (although I am not sure if this is enforced) - however the money isn't gone - it is transferred to a merchant. The merchant must have an agreement with a bank somewhere, so unlike, say, Western Union transfers, it isn't anonymous. Also, typically your credit card company takes the fraud risk - you can dispute a charge

Comment: You can also require a valid billing address to charge the card as well. It is up to the stripe account holder to decide whether they accept payments without valid address information. This is just as secure as any other online transaction is capable of. You can accept payments with older ios versions, as well as ios8 devices that are not apple pay capable. You would need to use the stripe api, as well as stripe sdk. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: @Paulw11- I went through https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object where it is mentioned that a token is created everytime one makes a purchase/transaction. But my question still remains the same- suppose say for e.g. I accidently get your credit card then I make payment using your card very easily in a stripe enabled iOS app. As no password is required(password that only you(card owner)) knows. Let me know if I got this wrong.

Comment: Only the card holder knows the billing address and the zip code. Both can be required in addition to the cvc to process the transaction.